# How to validate Xml in that specific way

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt, xsd

My problem is that i dont know how to properly write a xsd that allows me to validate xml in such way :

i need to have few necessary nodes (in any order) and to allow any other nodes to be in root

so for example i need to validate such xml, with 2 necessary nodes:

```
<root>
    <necessary1/>
    <someRandomNode1/>
    <necessary2/>
    <someRandomNode2/>
    <someRandomNode3/>
</root>
```

but this has to be in any order and `<xs:any/>` is probably not what im looking for.

edit:

this 'someRandomNodeX' is not name of node, it can be everything. Number of this unscpecified nodes is unknown too.

Comment: Do you have only 5 types of nodes under root?

Comment: In that case, I think you're in for a disappointment: *"Anything in any order but if it's element x then ..."* isn't something that Xsd can handle.

Comment: But this is makes no sense that tool such xsd cannot handle validating for few necessary nodes and dont care about rest of them...
Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution if the required elements and the non-required elements can be made in different namespaces. It requires XML Schema 1.1.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" vc:minVersion="1.1"
    xmlns:namespace="http://www.example.com/"
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/">
    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="necessary1" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="necessary2" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:any namespace="##other" processContents="lax"/>
                <xs:any namespace="##local" processContents="lax"/>
            </xs:choice>
            <xs:assert test="exactly-one(namespace:necessary1) and exactly-one(namespace:necessary2)"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

This validates:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<namespace:root
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com test.xsd"
      xmlns:namespace="http://www.example.com/">
    <namespace:necessary1/>
    <someRandomNode1/>
    <namespace:necessary2/>
    <someRandomNode2/>
    <someRandomNode3/>
</namespace:root>
```